# impossible to find a solution on Selenium for permanent overlay

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox

I am looking for a solution on that particular [website](https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/#login) to click 
button with  XPath = '//*[@id="num-pad"]/button[3]' but I keep failing

**current behavior**

Using this piece of code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
timeout=20
browser.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)
browser.get("https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/#login")
button='//*[@id="num-pad"]/button[3]'
login='//*[@id="identifiant"]'
cbutton='//*[@id="maploginKeyboard"]/area[8]'

WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, button)))

browser.find_element(By.XPATH, button).click()
```

I am having the exception

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element ....is not clickable at point (841.5,483.25) because another element..... obscures it

So I dig the internet a bit and most of what I found seems to come from a permanent overlay issue but replacing the last line by the below does not click the designated button

```
element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, button)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

**Expected behavior**

Find a piece of code which allow to click the designated button with following XPath = `'//*[@id="num-pad"]/button[3]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same issue a couple of times...

My best solution for you is to use `ActionChains`.

I have added it to your code and it works for me!

Here is the working snipp:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
timeout=20
browser.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)
browser.get("https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/#login")
button='//*[@id="num-pad"]/button[3]'
login='//*[@id="identifiant"]'
cbutton='//*[@id="maploginKeyboard"]/area[8]'

WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, button)))
print("found the element")

my_buttton = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, button)

action = ActionChains(browser)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(my_buttton, 5, 5)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

Hope you find this helpful!

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot Moshe. I saw that piece of code in some Java post but was unable to translate into Python (did not really search too much either). Would you know  what does "move_to_element_with_offset" method exactly do?

Comment: Thanks! @JBRolland Hopefully soon(now) you will! Just keep on contributing to the community!

Comment: Done. Thx again